# How do you set the status bar or safe area to remove white space on iPhone X?

Tags: ios, swift, ios11, iphone-x, safearealayoutguide

I have added the option to use safe area guidelines yet when I view the app it appears to respect the safe area but theres some white space that I cant get rid of. I dont know what is causing it nor do I know how to change the color from white.

I've set the background color to what you see below.

```
view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.227, green:0.251, blue:0.294, alpha:1)
```

I've also set the white status bar style

```
UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.lightContent
```

[image]

My main Storyboard

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: It's hard to know without more details, but my guess is the white area is a `UIView` that was used to color the area behind the status bar on previous iOS devices. Is there a view that's being added to that location in the storyboard or in code?

Comment: @nathan I think you might be right. It is part of the view, not sure how that space is being added though. Ill post more images of my main storyboard.

Comment: what are the constraints on your web view?

Comment: @nathan turned out it was the WebView.top constraint. It was set to position based on the superview. I changed it to safe guideline and then it positioned with -24 constraint. I changed that to 0. Not sure why it was 24 and I'm hoping that it will work correctly for all phone types now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When the view is visible onscreen, this guide reflects the portion of
>   the view that is not covered by navigation bars, tab bars, toolbars,
>   and other ancestor views. (In tvOS, the safe area reflects the area
>   not covered the screen's bezel.) If the view is not currently
>   installed in a view hierarchy, or is not yet visible onscreen, the
>   layout guide edges are equal to the edges of the view.

You need to set constraints with safeArea
Set top, bottom, leading, trailing constraints of `webView` with `safeArea`
with constant 0, Hence your objects will not clip.
[image]

**Programmatically as:**

```
 webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            let guide = self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
            webView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
            webView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
            webView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
            webView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.topAnchor).isActive = true
        }
```

[SafeAreaGuide](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/2891102-safearealayoutguide)

Comment: I believe this would have solved the issue. I think I had to also make sure the safe area constraint for the top was set to 0 as well. Even though my webview constraints were all set to 0, I had to set the wC wR field of the top alignment constraint to 0.

Comment: Yes! Align to safe area with `constant =0` or higher

Answer (score 1):

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
     webView.scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never;
}
```